# Off-topic Migration Paths

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Now that the site is out of beta, presumably we're going to get migration paths set up to the other sites. It would stand to reason adding [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) would be a no-brainer, but are there any other migration paths that should be set up?

Comment: Don't forget to post evidence of questions that should have been migrated and that there are only 4 free "slots" to fill.

Answer (score 5):

It's rare but sometimes questions belonging to SF show up here. I think the most migration paths needed, besides SO, are in beta/commit or even in definition phase.

Answer (score 4):

Off hand, I would think that [Super User](https://superuser.com/) might also be a good one to be able to send questions to. Beyond that, questions relevant to [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Webapps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) might show up from time to time, but I suspect they would be quite rare.

Comment: If you can find questions that fit these site then post their links. It will help get the migration path set up.

Answer (score 4):

Some questions that should have been migrated to Stack Overflow (had the option existed):

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2979/how-do-you-set-sourcegear-vault-as-the-scc-for-vs2010-closed

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3597/questions-related-to-search-engine-friendly-urls-closed

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4509/bitwise-operator-predence-closed

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1840/creating-a-vb-log-in-page-using-an-already-existing-program-closed

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5365/open-a-new-window-and-call-javascript-function-closed

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6933/java-exception-handling-i-want-to-repair-errors-closed

There are others, these are from the first few pages of closed questions.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some questions that have recently been migrated to SO by the mods:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998425/use-mingw-in-eclipse-on-linux

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994258/turn-off-visual-studio-vb-net-lines-around-each-method

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993600/speech-to-text-converter

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991764/find-d-square-no

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979076/jquery-wcf-http-404-error

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957995/customizing-the-nunit-gui-for-data-driven-testing

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949633/copy-parts-of-a-buffer-in-c

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946068/using-windows-intergrated-autenifcation-with-sqlroleprovider-in-silverlight-appli

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't know if they should be made now, since I haven't looked through the closed questions, but some possible Stack Exchanges that should be linked:

- Unix and Linux (when it comes out of Beta, of course)
- User Interface
- Game Development
- Web Applications
- On Startups
- Super User
- Server Fault
- Stack Overflow

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest that we add an option 'Other' when flagging a question as off-topic that belongs on a different SE.

I have just flagged one question that was about software license / disclaimers that really was about law and what you can do in a disclaimer and if placing a tool which could be illegal in the public domain as in github or bitbucket.

I had to mark it as blatantly off-topic, but that is not really nice neither to the asker nor to the flagger, feeling not being that polite to someone looking for help.

I don't think it is needed to actually be able to write which SE site it should be moved to, as that can be done in a comment on the question in a polite way.

Comment: Note: no question is ever closed as "blatantly" off-topic unless a close-voter (3k+) takes the time to write exactly that in their custom comment. That's just a placeholder for *flaggers*, who don't get the option to write a comment that's also a close vote.

Comment: Ah ok. I will feel less bad next time ;-)

Comment: If there is no direct migration path *and* you feel the question is a good quality, on-topic question at another site: flag the question for moderator review and make your case for migration. Moderators can migrate anywhere.